# Views arguments as part of path

Tags: 7, views

Is it possible to create views pages with urls like "prefix-%-postfix" instead of "prefix/%/postfix"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The menu router system only understands `%` as placeholder within `/` characters as an argument to pass through to the callback function that will render it. It won't understand `prefix-%-postfix` other than its literal value. The underlying function, `arg()`, that the Views `Content ID from URL` contextual filter relies on to retrieve an argument relies on this system so it wouldn't be able to pull the argument.